# Array index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I have a tableView where I'd like to display my comments for example how instagram and many other social networks do. 3 comments below the post, here's an image to explain: [image]

as you can see from that image, at the top you have the post, then the caption, and finally the 3 latest comments.

I have added a commentng system to my app, and I can view all the comments when I click on the comment icon and I get redirected to the new VC.

I also have a UUID for each post for when I'm adding the caption, So I think that could help in some way for connecting the comments to the post!

But now I'm looking to achieve this.

So far I have added 3 UIlabels in my storyboard below my post, then I have made a collection outlet for those labels. Now in my table view I have a query for getting the latest 3 comments :

```
var commentUsername = [String]()
var commentArray = [String]()


let Commentquery = PFQuery(className: "Comments")
Commentquery.whereKey("toPost", containedIn: self.uuidArray)
Commentquery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
Commentquery.limit = 3
Commentquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        self.commentUsername.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.commentArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        for object in objects! {
            self.commentArray.append(object.objectForKey("comment") as! String)
             self.commentUsername.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)
        }
        tableView.reloadData
     }
})
```

And then here is how I display them in my CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
var counter = (indexPath.row * 3)
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! NewsFeedTableViewCell

for comments in cell.threeComments{
    comments.text = commentArray[counter++]
    comments.sizeToFit()
}
```

It's on that line "comments.text = commentArray[counter++]" that I'm getting *Array index out of range*.

I'm guessing that I am receiving this error because its either return nil because there's no comments for that photo or there's not atleast 3 comments to fill the UILabels in...And that's what I have had difficulty with for a while now, If anyone knows how to fix or the correct possible "optional" query or something that would be great!!

For any further explanation please just comment below.

Best regards & thanks in advance!

Full code :

```
     var usernameArray = [String]()
    var profilePicture = [PFFile]()
    var dateArray = [NSDate?]()
    var postArray = [PFFile]()
    var titleArray = [String]()
    var uuidArray = [String]()
    var followArray = [String]()

    var commentUsername = [String]()
    var commentArray = [String]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadPosts()
    }



    func loadPosts() {
        let followQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follows")
        followQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        followQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.followArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                for object in objects! {
                    self.followArray.append(object.valueForKey("following") as! String)

                }

                 self.followArray.append(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
                let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                query.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.followArray)
                query.limit = self.page
                query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                        self.profilePicture.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                        self.dateArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                        self.postArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                        self.titleArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                        self.uuidArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                        for object in objects! {

                            self.usernameArray.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String)


                            self.profilePicture.append(object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)
                            self.dateArray.append(object.createdAt)
                            self.postArray.append(object.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)
                            self.titleArray.append(object.valueForKey("caption") as! String)

                            self.uuidArray.append(object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String)


                        }

                        let Commentquery = PFQuery(className: "Comments")
                        Commentquery.whereKey("toPost", containedIn: self.uuidArray)
                        Commentquery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
                        Commentquery.limit = 3
                        Commentquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                self.commentUsername.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                                self.commentArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                                for object in objects! {
                                    self.commentArray.append(object.objectForKey("comment") as! String)
                                   self.commentUsername.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)

                                }


                                self.tableView.reloadData()


                            }else {
                                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        })


                    } else {

                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                        }
                })
            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

    }




    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }





    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return uuidArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

          var counter = (indexPath.row * 3)

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! NewsFeedTableViewCell

        for comments in cell.threeComments{

                comments.text = commentArray[counter++]
                comments.sizeToFit()
    }


      }
}
```

Comment: A better way to do this would be to use a 2D Array for commentUsername, then you can iterate through things directly rather than assuming a hard-coded amount in each set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jack - I think the solution is going to be very similar to your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854857/how-to-order-2-tableview-sections/35866457?noredirect=1#comment59402360_35866457 and you should look at storing the username & comment text in a struct, and loading the query results into that.

If everything is loaded into an array called `comments`, then you still have a choice - either have a single label showing all three lines (set number of lines = 3 in storyboard), or have three labels

```
// single label
myLabel.text = ""
for comment in comments
{
    myLabel.text += comment.text + "\n"
}

// multiple labels approach, assuming labels have tag value 100, 101, 102
for index in 0..<comments.count
{
    let label = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100 + index) as! UILabel 
    label.text = comments[index]
}
```

** updated - cell.contentView.viewWithTag **

I have used tag values starting at 100 rather than 0, to avoid any accidental matches with default values

Here's how you set the `tag` value.  In this example, I have two custom cells, and the yellow cell has three labels.  If you select each label in turn, and set the `Tag` attribute as shown, then every instance of the cell that is created will have those three labels with the same tags - but you only search within the context of an individual cell, so it doesn't matter about the other instances.

[image: set Tag for label]

Comment: I think I have it working, just not sure about the tag bit... How would I add the tags in tableViewCell file?

Comment: So i don't need to make a outlet for the labels?

Comment: Ok it's working, Can you check the chat when you have time!

Comment: well - you could, but more sensibly with an Outlet Collection rather than individual Outlets - but it does effectively the same thing as we're doing here

Answer (score 2):

inside the tableview function (CellForRowAtIndexPath) indexPath.row gives current cell index number no need to iterate using a loop, if you need 3 cells you have to set it in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return commentArray.count // you can set static number 3 here, instead of set 'commentArray.count'
}
```

.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! NewsFeedTableViewCell
    comments.text = commentArray[indexPath.row]
    comments.sizeToFit()
}
```

you can change your loop like this

```
for (index, comments) in cell.threeComments {
    comments.text = commentArray[index]
    comments.sizeToFit()
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I'm not sure If what I need is three cells... as there will be a photos ect all contained in the 1 cell... I need to display 3 comment in that cell don't I? because if I repeat it 3 times for the comment sow ill the image get repeated..?

Comment: @Jack can you put entire viewController code block here then I can understand the problem.. (commentArray structure and uitableview delegate and datasource methods also enough)

Comment: Hi I added most of it above

Comment: in your numberOfRowsInSection method return 1 that means you have one cell, but in cellForRowAtIndexPath indexpath.row is 0 index (0,1,2,3,..) you only have one cell so current value of the  indexpath.row = 0 , therefore (indexpath.row*3) == 0

Comment: before the for in loop,print variables then you can get the idea ex: print(cell.threeComments.count) 
print(counter)
print(commentArray)

Comment: Hmm I think I understand what you're saying, anyway I tried the loop code you added...But I'm getting this weird error I do not understand: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AH56f.png

Comment: did you put all three comment in one label ? now it is wired to me too.. try to debug the code print() variables and get some understand

Comment: Yeh all the labels are in a collection outlet... I'll try

Comment: Can't seem to figure it out!! I'm getting this error even with just a normal uilabel...http://i.stack.imgur.com/sKsJJ.png

Answer (score 0):

This design needs to be improved, (see comment) but to avoid the crash you could simply do:

```
for comments in cell.threeComments{
     if commentsArray.count < counter {
         comments.text = commentArray[counter]
         comments.sizeToFit()
     }
     counter += 1
}
```

FYI, I removed the counter++ as unary operators are being removed in Swift 3.0

Comment: I tried that, but seem to get the error anyway...What way would you reccomend? how would you do this? –